# ApacheIgnite TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder fails in Azure Kubernetes cluster in a vNet

Tags: ignite, azure-aks, azure-virtual-network

```
vNet IP Address space: 10.106.8.0/22
Apache Ignite version: 2.9.1
Kubernetes version: 1.19.7
Service CIDR: 10.0.0.0/16
DNS Service IP: 10.0.0.10
Docker bridge CIDS: 172.17.0.1/16
```

We deployed a AKS cluster in a vNet after that deployed Apache Ignite cluster 2.9.1. The sqlline.sh and thin client (dotnet) was able to connect using port 10800 and internal load balancer IP Address. But, the server node (clientmode=true, dotnet thick client) wasn't able to connect (xml config file attached) below is the error.
Any help to resolve the issue is much appreciated.

```
[Error] [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder on start
```

After the above, below error repeats forever...

```
[06:04:20] [Error] [org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=tcp-client-disco-msg-worker, threadName=tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4-#35, blockedFor=13s]
[06:04:20] [Warn] [] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=Unmodifia[72901-default-config.xml][1]bleSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=tcp-client-disco-msg-worker, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1614578647003]]]
[06:04:20] [Warn] [org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheDiagnosticManager] Page locks dump:
```

Apache Ignite server nodes were deployed in **cohort-store** k8s namespace...

kubectl get pods -n cohort-store

```
NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cohortstore-0   1/1     Running   0          3d6h
cohortstore-1   1/1     Running   0          3d6h
cohortstore-2   1/1     Running   0          3d6h
```

kubectl -n cohort-store get svc

```
kubectl -n cohort-store get svc
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                                          AGE
cohortstore-load-balancer-internal   LoadBalancer   10.0.113.146   10.106.8.255   8080:31417/TCP,10800:32719/TCP,10900:31208/TCP   29h
```

Apache Ignite client node (dotnet think client) was deployed in **cohort-frontdoor** k8s namespace...

kubectl get pods -n cohort-frontdoor

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cohortfrontdoor-665f99bb6b-tdl5z   1/1     Running   0          72m
```

Client XML **SpringConfig** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
        Configuration example with Kubernetes IP finder and Ignite persistence enabled.
        WAL files and database files are stored in separate disk drives.
    -->
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="clientmode" value="true"/>
        <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="5000"/>
        <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="10000"/>
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="ephi"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                    <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>
                    <property name="backups" value="0"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="networkTimeout" value="10000" />
                <property name="localPort" value="47500" />
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                            Enables Kubernetes IP finder and setting custom namespace and service names.
                        -->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                        <property name="namespace" value="cohort-store"/>
                        <property name="serviceName" value="cohortstore-load-balancer-internal"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="socketTimeout" value="300" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="slowClientQueueLimit" value="1000"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Nodes outside of K8S can't use K8S discovery.

Comment: @alamar thanks for the reply. In my case, all server nodes are within the K8S address space. Its just that nodes (think client) are different K8S namespace.

Comment: Trace logs...

[20:21:19] [Debug] [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder] Getting Apache Ignite endpoints from: https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443/api/v1/namespaces/cohort-store/endpoints/cohortstore-load-balancer-internal
[20:21:20] [Error] [org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=tcp-client-disco-msg-worker, threadName=tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4-#35, blockedFor=182s]

Answer (score 0):

The error went away after I did clusterRoleBinding (see below for more info). I thought, had to do this, since my Ignite server nodes and the think client nodes are in two different K8S namespaces & had two different service accounts.

But now, below is what I'm see in a big loop on the server nodes...

```
INFO: TCP discovery accepted incoming connection [rmtAddr=/10.106.8.32, rmtPort=43883]
Mar 02, 2021 12:02:44 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger info
INFO: TCP discovery spawning a new thread for connection [rmtAddr=/10.106.8.32, rmtPort=43883]
Mar 02, 2021 12:02:44 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger info
INFO: Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/10.106.8.32:43883, rmtPort=43883]
Mar 02, 2021 12:02:44 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger info
INFO: Initialized connection with remote client node [nodeId=59a5ce6f-2d0d-4abb-aaf5-b2b9f51f7e44, rmtAddr=/10.106.8.32:43883]
Mar 02, 2021 12:02:44 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger info
INFO: Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/10.106.8.32:43883, rmtPort=43883
Mar 02, 2021 12:02:46 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger info
```

**clusterrolebinding info**

```
k describe clusterrolebinding cohortstore-RoleBinding
Name:         cohortstore-RoleBinding
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: cohortstore
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: cohort-store
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  cohortstore-Role
Subjects:
  Kind            Name                  Namespace
  ----            ----                  ---------
  ServiceAccount  cohortstore.com       cohort-store
  ServiceAccount  cohort-frontdoor.com  cohort-frontdoor
```